# Dynamically setting links to text in strings.xml

Tags: android, text, dynamic, localization, hyperlink

I'm trying to make an app with localisation built in, but I want a way that I can create a web link within the text, the URL being defined elsewhere (for ease of maintenance).

So, I have my links in res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...
    <string name="link1">http://some.link.com</string>
    <string name="link2">http://some.link2.com</string>
</resources>
```

and my localised text in res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...
    <string name="sampleText">Sample text\nMore text and link1\nMore text and link2.</string>
</resources>
```

I've not tested this bit, but from the [localization section of developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#strategies) it says that this approach to reducing content duplication should work, although I'm not sure what folder I should put Italian, for example.  Would it be in 'res/values-it-rIT/strings.xml'?  Lets assume that I have various other languages too.

I'm looking for a way of taking the base localised 'sampleText' and inserting my html links in, and getting them to work when clicked on.  I've tried two approaches so far:

1,

Putting some formatting in the 'sampleText' (%s):

```
<string name="sampleText">Sample text\nMore text and <a href="%s">link1</a>\nMore text and <a href="%s">link2</a>.</string>
```

and then processing the text like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHolder);
tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sampleText, getResources().getString(R.string.link1), getResources().getString(R.string.link2)));
```

But this didn't work when I click on the link, even though the link text is being put in to the correct places.

2, I tried to use Linkify but the regular expression route may be difficult as I'm looking at supporting non-Latin based languages.  I tried to put a custom xml tag around the link text and then do something like this:

```
Pattern wordMatcher = Pattern.compile("<span1>.*</span1>");
String viewURL =    "content://" + getResources().getString(R.string.someLink);
Linkify.addLinks(tv, wordMatcher , viewURL );
```

But this didn't work either.

So, I'd like to know if there's a way of dynamically adding multiple URLs to different sections of the same text which will link to web content?

Comment: maybe you can mark @dule's answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is your "a href" link tags are within `strings.xml` and being parsed as tags when  `strings.xml` is parsed, which you don't want. Meaning you need to have it ignore the tags using XML's CDATA:

`<string name="sampleText">Sample text <![CDATA[<a href="http://www.google.com">link1</a>]]></string>`

And then you can continue with `Html.fromHtml()` and make it clickable with `LinkMovementMethod`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHolder);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.sampleText)));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Don't forget the http:// in the web address, otherwise I get a "No Activity found to handle intent" error

Comment: Thanks! The cleanest answer!

Comment: String resources are not documented to support arbitrary HTML tags. [The only documented and supported ones](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML) are `<b>`, `<i>`, and `<u>`. I do not recommend relying upon anything else, such as `<a>`, working across all Android versions and devices.

Answer (score 5):

In your layout set `android:autoLink` to `web`

```
<TextView android:text="@string/text_with_url"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

And in strings.xml just add the URL(s).

```
<string name="text_with_url">http://stackoverflow.com/ FTW!</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Html.fromHtml()` to convert the HTML into a `Spannable` that you put into the `TextView`. With what you have in #1, I would expect the `TextView` to show the HTML source, not rendered HTML.

Comment: with the sample text from #1 I've tried this:  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string. sampleText, getResources().getString(R.string.someLink), getResources().getString(R.string.someLink2))), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
 but still not getting clickable links.  Am I missing something in the layout or is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: This might work then CharSequence str=getResources().getText(R.string. sampleText);

Comment: I'm not able to get it to work. It is just displaying hyperlink, which is not clickable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement

```
setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

on your Textview

Here is a better example:

[clickable-urls-in-android-textviews](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/)