# Setting Hyperlink Android in textview based on String.xml

Tags: android

my string.xml string line

```
 <string name="companyLink">&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.abc.com&quot;&gt;abc Technology &lt;/a> </string>
```

and this is how i try to use the html

```
    TextView   companylink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCompanyLink);
    companylink.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.companyLink)));
    companylink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

however android only display out the html without the hyperlink 
 on the screen

```
<a href=http://abc.com>abc string </a>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the all `&amp;` to `&`? You don't need to escape the ampersand character when using it in a HTML entity. That might be causing issues.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852184/android-textview-hyperlink/9852280#9852280)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes should also be escaped otherwise Java will remove them during getString().  Add backslashes before &quot;

```
<string name="companyLink">&lt;a href=\&quot;http://www.abc.com\&quot;&gt;abc Technology &lt;/a> </string>
```

Or this solution that worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949264/1011746

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax is:

> `<a href="http://abc.com">abc string </a>`