# how can I write this string?

Tags: android, string

I want put a link in my app, in actionbar, for sending email to others, for going to app market.

the app markets link, for opening chooser is:

market://details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati

I write this string in the string file in values folder:

```
<string name="myMail_Body">Hi \n\n install this app \n\n click this link for going to your favorite market: \n\n market://details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati" </string>
```

now, when app send email to others, market link is not a link and email reciever can not click it. it is text.

what can I do?

please help.

---

I am in iran. we, irainian, can not put our app in google play.

I want opening the market chooser in mobile, and user can select his/her favorite market among installed apps in his/her mobile.

please help me to convert:

"market://details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati"

to a link in email body.

the problem is that: my address does not "http://".

when I try other address with prefix "http://", it works good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779129/setting-hyperlink-android-in-textview-based-on-string-xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a http url:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati
```

Many e-mail clients will show that as a clickable link.

Comment: I am in iran. we, irainian, can not put our app in google play.

I want opening the market chooser in mobile, and user can select his/her favorite market among installed app in his/her mobile.

please help me to convert:
"market://details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati"
to a link in email body.

Answer (score 0):

use this below function...

```
 <string name="myMail_Body">Hi! I am using this awseome app. Please find this from <a href="market://details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati">here</a></string>


public void shareThisApp()
        {
          final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          intent.setType("text/html");
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android App");
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getResource.getString(Html.fromHtml(R.string.myMail_Body)));

          try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an action"));
          } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // (handle error)
          }
        }
```

Comment: my language is persian. and I do not want put my email body text in java file. I want to put it as a string in string file, until I can translate it to other languages.

Comment: I am in iran. we, irainian, can not put our app in google play. I want opening the market chooser in mobile, and user can select his/her favorite market among installed apps in his/her mobile. please help me to convert: "market://details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati" to a link in email body. 
the problem is that:
my address does not "http://". 
when I try other address with prefix "http://", it works good.

Comment: error in string file : Open quote is expected for attribute "href" associated with an element type "a".

Comment: error in this section: getResource.getString(Html.fromHtml(R.string.myMail_Body))

The method fromHtml(String) in the type Html is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: my app ia a navegation drawer.

Comment: please look at this code: 

getResource.getString(Html.fromHtml(R.string.myMail_Body)) 

is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the below line in string.xml file and try to class that where you require...

```
<string name="share_text_content">https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati</string>
```

Comment: I am in iran. we, irainian, can not put our app in google play.

I want opening the market chooser in mobile, and user can select his/her favorite market among installed apps in his/her mobile.

please help me to convert:
"market://details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati"
to a link in email body.

Comment: Try this one..
It is working for me..

    String link_val = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.shandel.maghalat.shariati"
    String body = "<a href=\"" + link_val + "\">" + link_val+ "</a>"

    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));

Comment: why do you put link_val twice?

Comment: second link_val is what ever you want you can have like "download our app" instead of writing  link_val..

Comment: the problem is that: my address does not "http://". when I try other address with prefix "http://", it works good.