# Making an hyperlink in a Textview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, hyperlink

I have a lot of text, and I want to make a link in the middle of that.

This is how it looks like, and the www.rkz.nl is what i want to be a link.

[image]

Comment: just use Html.fromhtml(add link);

Comment: I did that in my main activity, but how do I connect that to a text part in strings.xml?

Comment: nvm i got it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following property to textview

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Answer (score 0):

make that text in the string file and then connect the string with the link you want

Comment: That's the point, I already have all the text in the string file, just want to know how i can get that part in to a link. How do i connect it

Answer (score 0):

**Using Xml**

```
<TextView
android:text="Click my My Url: www.google.com"
android:id="@+id/tvUrl"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:autoLink="web">
```

programmatically

```
 final TextView tvUrl= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUrl);
    tvUrl.setText("Click my My Url: www.google.com");
    Linkify.addLinks(tvUrl, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Answer (score 0):

found a similar question try this 
[Dynamically setting links to text in strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244194/dynamically-setting-links-to-text-in-strings-xml)
or try this

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

here google will be displayed as a link